# React Native: Why is this screen rendering differently in snack.expo.io than on my device?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator, expo

I have this screen in my React Native app: https://snack.expo.io/@gkeenley/playful-blueberries

It renders fine in that snack ^^ for web (the default emulator), but for Android the image gets a height of zero and doesn't appear.

Does anyone know how I can approach debugging this?

**UPDATE**

If I remove `flex: 1` on the `icon` style, it fixes it. But I don't understand why that makes a difference and why you need to do it for Android but not web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have description in [document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/height-and-width) about "Flex Dimensions" and notice.

> A component can only expand to fill available space if its parent has dimensions greater than 0. If a parent does not have either a fixed width and height or flex, the parent will have dimensions of 0 and the flex children will not be visible.

Comment: Do you know why this would be different for web vs Android?

Comment: I think flex work in web and react-native have a little bit different, one is reading by web browser, and another is use same method to achieve the effect but work on Android. Maybe just work different so have notice in the end of it to remind people who have experience using CSS?